# ZF2 SharedManager attach redirect ignored if php shows notice

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2, acl

i have a simple ACL check with a redirect if access not granted and send back a 401 if a post request is sended.

```
if (!$e->getViewModel()->acl->hasResource($route) || !$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($role, $route)) {
        //Naughty trying to get somewhere they shouldn't (Clear there identity force them to login again)
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        //location to page or what ever
        if($request->isPost())
        {
            $response->setStatusCode(401);
            return $response;
        }
        else
        {
            return $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e)  {
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controller->redirect()->toRoute('auth');
            }, -11);
        }
    }
```

Now i added in some SQL Queries a "WHERE id = user->id"

But because the user is not logged in the PHP will throw a notice

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID

and dont redirect anymore.

This just happend on the dev-server because the prod-server doesnt show errors/notice but this still make me really unconfortable. Is this normal or is there a way to "force" the redirect anyway?

I tried to attach it to different events but doesnt change the behavoir

Greetings

Comment: I've a feeling that it is your display_errors php setting. It should be turned off, so it won't be part of the output.

Comment: @netiul yeah it is, but why the view is still rendered? And on the prod-server where are no errors displayed i still get a entry in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on our comments of the question.
The [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting just

> determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part of
>   the output or if they should be hidden from the user.

It's not the setting that decides what errors/warning should be logged to log files. If display_errors is turned on, and output is not buffered, it will be send to the client (likely via a webserver) immediately. 
Since headers are always send first to the client, your application send a 200 OK status code before outputting the warning message. So any status code your try to send after is lost. That's why your 401 redirect didn't work on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was just that i didnt return the redirect...
If you return it in ZF2 it will interrupt the current process otherwise it will attach it to  the end.

```
if (!$e->getViewModel()->acl->hasResource($route) || !$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($role, $route)) {
    //Naughty trying to get somewhere they shouldn't (Clear there identity force them to login again)
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    //location to page or what ever
    if($request->isPost())
    {
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        return $response;
    }
    else
    {
        return $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e)  {
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            return $controller->redirect()->toRoute('auth');
        }, -11);
    }
}
```

Comment: Redirect helper returns Response object. The fact that redirect worked at all is a side effect of changing state of the shared Response object. That will be impossible in the future once immutable PSR-7 request/response are incorporated into the framework.

Comment: @Xerkus how should i do this otherwise?